# How to make arrow functions work on IOS 9.3.1?

Tags: javascript, ios, babeljs

I like using the fetch API & ES6 arrow functions but I am struggling to get a simple example to work on IOS Safari 9.3.1.

```js
function foobar() {
  fetch("https://httpbin.org/get", {
      method: "GET"
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log("Fail zone");
    })
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.ok) {
        res.json().then((json) => {
          document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json, null, 2);
        });
      } else {
        console.log("error", res);
      }
    });
}
```

```html
<button onClick="foobar(this);">Just testing</button>
<pre id=response></pre>
```

What Javascript includes am I missing to make it work in IOS? Not enthused about creating my own bundle.js.

When I use the fetch polyfill & `type="text/babel"` upon https://react.dabase.com/foo/ I get **ReferenceError: Can't find variable** in Safari's inspector.

Also I get **Uncaught ReferenceError: foobar is not defined** in Chrome. What am I missing?

Comment: If arrow functions aren't supported in your target environment yet, transpile the code like everyone else does.

Comment: Yes, I'm struggling to transpile...

Comment: There are ways to transpile the code in the browser, but that's all junk; you can't use that in production anyway. The no-frills [babel-cli](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/) tool gets the job done with little room for things to go wrong. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make arrow functions work I installed `npm install babel-cli babel-preset-es2015` & then ran:

```
./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel.js --presets es2015 main.js -o compiled.js
```

As for Fetch API support in IOS I've just sourced https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/1.0.0/fetch.min.js

If there is a better way, please let me know.